# Custom Facets in Liferay 7.1 using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, facet, liferay-7.1

Is it possible to create custom facets in 7.1 with Elasticsearch 6.1?

Under the System Settings > Search > Elasticsearch configuration is a textbox for 'Additional Index Configurations' and 'Additional Type Mappings'. If I were to create a custom Web Content Structure with let's say a 'State' field, how would I then configure that?

How would I create mappings that associate with the structure that I created?

This is for a job board with searchable facets like Employment Type (Part Time/Full Time...) , Telecommute, etc.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Yes, I also posted this on the official Liferay forums. 
https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/110663338

Comment: @SeanGildea did you find a way to create a custom facet in 7.1 ? in my use case has the facet has to combine several values

Comment: As of last September, I never found a way. I stopped using Liferay after I reached out to the Liferay dev team via their Slack directly and they were not able to update their documentation or provide examples. There is no documentation on how to implement on their website, no concrete details, just statements that it's possible. 

We ended up moving away from Liferay 7.1 to Spring 5